# Implicit typecasting from double to int?

Tags: c

```
// Assuming these definitions
int x; 
float y;
```

What is the difference between this:

```
  x = y = 7.5;
```

and this:

```
  y = x = 7.5;
```

How come the first one prints `y` value as `7.5`,
and second one prints `y` as `7.00`?

Comment: `int x; float y;` are not *initializations*, they are *definitions*

Comment: On the wording: Casting is never implicit, because it implies being explicit. What you observe is implicit *conversion*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The explanation is very simple: `=` is right to left associative, which means `x = y = 7.5;` is evaluated as `x = (y = 7.5);` hence essentially the same as:

```
y = 7.5;   // value is converted from double to float, y receives 7.5F
x = y;     // value of y is converted from float to int, x receives 7 (truncated toward 0)
```

Whereas `y = x = 7.5;` is evaluated as `y = (x = 7.5);`:

```
x = 7.5;   // 7.5 is converted to int, x receives value 7 (truncated toward 0)
y = x;     // value of x is converted to float, y receives 7.0F
```

These implicit conversions can be counter intuitive. You might want to increase the warning level to let the compiler warn you about potential mistakes and unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 4):

An assignment chain like you show, is evaluated from right to left.

```
x = y = 7.5;
```

is the same as

```
x = (y = 7.5);
```

Furthermore the result of an assignment is the assigned value.
This means that `7.5` (type `double`) is implicitely cast to `float` and then assigned to `y`. The result (`7.5f`) is then assigned to `x`. During this assignment the value is cast to `int` and the result is `7` which is stored in `x`.

If you switch the order you get different types:

```
y = x = 7.5;
```

Now `7.5` (type `double`) is implicitely cast to `int` and then assigned to `x`. The result is `7` which is assigned to `y`. Now that value is cast to `double` but the fraction is already lost and you will get `7.0f` being stored in `y`.

Answer (score 2):

In second expression

```
y = x = 7.5; /* multiple assignment operator. R->L associativity */
```

`x = 7.5` evaluates first and you are assigning a real floating value `7.5` to an integer `x` which leads to truncation of fractional part, hence `x` gets assigned with `7` instead of `7.5` and later on `y` gets assigned with `7.00000`

From the **C99** Standard **section 6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer**

> When a **finite value of real floating type** is converted to an
>   **integer type** other than _Bool, the **fractional part is discarded** (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the **value
>   of the integral part** cannot be represented by the **integer type**,
>   the behavior is **undefined**.